# I need some help with Geometry. Is this a correct answer to this problem?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, problem-solving

Good day,

I have a question regarding geometry. I don't know whether my answer is correct because the answer in my book uses a totally different method for solving this particular problem.

Here's the problem:

Given is a triangle, *ABC*, in which the middle of AB is also the middle of the circle drawn outside of the triangle. Finally, we draw a line from *C* to *M* where *M* signifies the point in the middle of *AB.* Now you have angle C sub 1 and angle C sub 2 ( together: angle C sub 12.)

We have created 2 equal-sided triangles, within the triangle *ABC*, within the circle, namely:
triangle ACM and triangle BCM.

**Proof that angle C sub 12 is equal to 90 degrees.**

My answer:

Given:

AM = MC = MB (2 equal-sided triangles)

To Proof:

$$\angle C_{12} = 90^{\circ}$$

Proof:
$$
\left.\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  &  & \\
\angle A + \angle M_{1} + \angle C_{1} = 180^{\circ}\\ 
\angle B + \angle M_{2} + \angle C_{2} = 180^{\circ}\\
\angle M_{2} + \angle 2B = 180^{\circ} \\ 
\angle M_{1} + \angle 2A = 180^{\circ} \\ 
\angle M_{1} + \angle M_{2} = 180^{\circ}\\
\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 180^{\circ} (= Q)\\
\\
\end{matrix}\right\}general
\\
$$

Calculate for angle A and angle B:

$$ \angle M_{2} + \angle 2B = 180^{\circ}\\
\angle 2B = 180^{\circ} - \angle M_{2}\\
\angle B = 90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{2} / 2) $$

$$and$$

$$ \angle M_{1} + \angle 2A = 180^{\circ}\\
\angle 2A = 180^{\circ} - \angle M_{1}\\
\angle A = 90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{1} / 2) $$
Also:
$$
\angle M_{2} = 180^{\circ} - \angle M_{1}\\
\angle M_{1} = 180^{\circ} - \angle M_{2}  (= U)\\
$$
Now we can put angle A and angle B in the sum of angles (indicated by Q in general section.):

$$(90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{1} / 2)) +  (90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{2} / 2)) + \angle C = 180^{\circ}$$

Now we substitute $$ \angle M_{1}$$ inside  $$((\angle M_{1} / 2)) $$ with U:

$$(90^{\circ} - (\frac{180^{\circ} - \angle M_{2}}{2}) + ((90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{2} / 2)) + \angle C = 180^{\circ}\\
(90^{\circ} - (\frac{180^{\circ}}{2}-\frac{\angle M_{2}}{2})) + (90^{\circ} - (\angle M_{2} / 2)) + \angle C = 180^{\circ}\\
90^{\circ} - \frac{180^{\circ}}{2}+\frac{\angle M_{2}}{2} + 90^{\circ} -\frac{\angle M_{2}}{2} + \angle C = 180^{\circ}\\
\Rightarrow 90^{\circ} + \angle C = 180^{\circ}\\
Conclusion: \angle C_{12} = 90^{\circ}
$$

(not the prettiest proof but hopefully you get the idea.)

Here's the more concise ( and beautiful ) proof from the answers in my book:

$$\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 180^{\circ} \Rightarrow \angle C_{1} + \angle C_{2} + \angle C_{12} = 180^{\circ} \Rightarrow \angle 2C_{12} = 180^{\circ} \Rightarrow \angle C_{12} = 90^{\circ} $$

If you need more information please ask and I'll provide the necessities.

Thanks!

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Geometry = draw the figure!

Comment: I thought I would get that question. I'll get to photoshop right away. Please give me a couple of sec.

Comment: In any case, this is a very simple question, for which you undertook a very complex answer. Your book is providing with a much simpler one. In mathematics, very often simple = elegant = clear.

Comment: I've added the picture. I know it's more elegant in my book.. Regardless, this was my first approach.

Comment: Additional comment: there is no Thales involved at any point here... Your title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: My figure is misleading. ABC in figure is not isosceles.

[image]

$$2x+2y = 180^\circ$$

$$x+y = ?$$

Comment: I've added a figure of my own. Sorry about that. Beautiful thinking though.

Comment: @Bowser No problem! actually i made it in paint. Also the triangle ABC is not isosceles, although my figure shows it as isosceles

Comment: How did you see the solution so quickly?

Comment: Actually, when you practice, you can apply your knowledge quickly. First thing in geometry is to do what Martigan said: Draw the figure. As soon as you draw the figure: you see isosceles triangles. Then you know that angles opposite to equal sides in a triangle are equal. So we have both angles equal. Now focus on what is needed to be calculated! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward.

$\angle A+\angle B+\angle C=\pi$

But given that $CM=AM=BM$, hence creating two isocele triangles $AMC$ and $BMC$ you have

$\angle A+\angle B=\angle C$

Hence the same as in your book $2\angle C=\pi$...

Comment: I don't fully understand.. I have to prove $$\angle C = 90^{\circ}$$ where does pi come from?

Comment: Sorry... $\pi$ is the value in rad, $180$ the value in degrees. It is the same...